# Creating Graph in Graphx using pair RDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have a pair RDD and want to construct a GraphX Graph using it. I want to have weighted edges i.e. if one edge appears 3 times in the pair RDD I want the edge weight to be `3`.

`take(1)` from the RDD looks like this:

```
res2: Array[(String, String)] = Array((905067378709,905458844980))
```

Comment: You want direct or undirect graph?

Comment: It doesnt matter too much, but directed graph would be better for my purposees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for directed Graph**

Let's suppose you have the follow pair RDD containg the edges:

```
val data: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    ("905067378709", "905458844980"),
    ("905067378709", "905458844980"),
    ("905458844980", "905067378709"),
    ("905067378709", "905458844980"),
    ("905458844982", "905458844984"),
    ("905067378709", "905458844984"),
    ("905067378712", "905067378709")))
```

create the follow RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)]:

```
val edgesRDD: RDD[(VertexId, VertexId)] = data.map { case (a, b) => (a.toLong, b.toLong) }
```

and then create the Graph with the function Graph.fromEdgeTuples.
This function allows creating a graph from only an RDD of edge tuples, assigning the edges the value 1, and automatically creating any vertices mentioned by edges and assigning them the default value.

```
val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(edgesRDD, 1)
// to print 
val vert: VertexRDD[Int] = graph.vertices
vert.foreach { println }

val edg: EdgeRDD[Int] = graph.edges
edg.foreach { println }
```

Now we can calculate the weight of duplicates edges:

```
val subgraph = graph.partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.CanonicalRandomVertexCut)
.groupEdges((a, b) => a + b)

// To print

val vert2: VertexRDD[Int] = subgraph.vertices
vert2.foreach { println }

val edg2: EdgeRDD[Int] = subgraph.edges
edg2.foreach { println }
```

The result is:

Edge(905067378712,905067378709,1)

Edge(905067378709,905458844984,1)

**Edge(905067378709,905458844980,3)** the edge occurred 3 times

Edge(905458844980,905067378709,1)

Edge(905458844982,905458844984,1)